# Cannot start Node.js: permission denied

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

I'm running Node.js server on Ubuntu 12.04. When I try to start server with `node server.js` I get

```
fs.js:438
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/scadge/nodejs/server.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:473:44)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

I also tried `sudo node server.js` and `sudo su` followed by `node server.js` - in all cases I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below.

Its permission issue.

1. Open terminal
2. Go the project directory.
3. run `chmod -R 777`

On everything that is related with access denied can be fix with this.

Thank You.